# Dell inspiron 14 5000 does not sync to correct time zone after change from GMT to BST and vice versa

Tags: windows-10, laptop, dell-inspiron, time

My laptop - Dell inspiron 14 5000 - does not syncronize to the correct time zone after a change i.e. when the UK goes from GMT to BST or vice versa.

I am able to "fix" the time by pressing the "Sync now" button on the Date & time settings page (without changing any other setting). I have that it set the time automatically and the time zone automatically (i.e. both are toggled on).

Does anyone know what the permanent fix for this is?

Edit 1:

Time server: time.windows.com
OS: Dual booted with Ubuntu, and Windows 10 Home - Issue only seen in Windows boot

I have checked for updates, and there are none to apply.

Changing the time server to uk.pool.ntp.org didn't help.

Comment: Testing the uk.pool.ntp.org - will update in a few days if needed - Thank you!

Comment: @Peregrino69 I can confirm that changing to uk.pool.ntp.org and it has not fixed the issue...